# Verification of a proof of some equivalents of AC

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I just opened an old file wherein I've worked several proofs as exercises, and discovered this one, along with the note "FIX THIS."

Unfortunately, I can't see what needs to be fixed, so either I'm missing it, or there was nothing to fix in the first place, or I already fixed it and forgot to delete the note. If any of the AC pros can spot the error(s) or verify the proof, I'd appreciate it. (*NB*: Herein, $0$ is the Von Neumann ordinal, the empty set.)

> The following are equivalent:
>
> (a) AC.
>
> (b) For any relation $R$ there is a function $f\subseteq R$ such that $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{dom}(R)$.
>
> (c) For any function $f$ there is a function $g$ such that $g(x)\in f(x)$ for all non-$0$ $x\in\operatorname{dom}(x)$.
>
> (d) For any function $f$ there is a function $g$ such that $\operatorname{dom}(g)=\operatorname{ran}(f)$ and such that $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)$.
>
> **Proof**
>
> $\bigl($(a)$\Rightarrow$(b)$\bigr)$ Let $R$ be a non-$0$ relation, so for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)$, the set $R[x]=\{y:x\:R\:y\}$ is non-$0$ by definition of $\operatorname{dom}(R)$. Let $f$ be a choice function for $\{R[x]\}_{x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)}$, and let $g:\operatorname{dom}(R)\to\operatorname{ran}(R)$ be the obvious map $\operatorname{dom}(R)\to\{R[x]\}_{x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)}$ composed with $f:\{R[x]\}_{x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)}\to\bigcup_{x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)}R[x]=\operatorname{ran}(R)$. Then $f:\operatorname{dom}(R)\to\operatorname{ran}(R)$ and $f\subseteq R$.
>
> $\bigl($(b)$\Rightarrow$(c)$\bigr)$ Let $f$ be a function with $\operatorname{dom}(f)=X$ and define a relation $R$ on $\bigl(X\smallsetminus\{0\}\bigr)\times\bigcup f[X]$ by $x\:R\:y$ iff $y\in f(x)$. If $x\in X\smallsetminus\{0\}$, then by definition there is some $y\in f(x)\subseteq\bigcup f[X]$, so $x\:R\:y$, and so $\operatorname{dom}(R)=X\smallsetminus\{0\}$. Let $g\subseteq R$ be a function such that $\operatorname{dom}(g)=\operatorname{dom}(R)=X\smallsetminus\{0\}$, so by definition of $R$, $g(x)\in f(x)$ for all $x\in X\smallsetminus\{0\}$.
>
> $\bigl($(c)$\Rightarrow$(a)$\bigr)$ Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a non-$0$ set of non-$0$ sets, and let $f=\{\langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle:\alpha\in\mathcal{A}\}$. A function $g$ as guaranteed by (c) is (once restricted to $\mathcal{A}$, if necessary) precisely a choice function for $\mathcal{A}$.
>
> $\bigl($(b)$\Rightarrow$(d)$\bigr)$ Let $R=f^{-1}$--a relation, but not necessarily a function--so that $\operatorname{dom}(R)=\operatorname{ran}(f)$ and $\operatorname{dom}(f)=\operatorname{ran}(R)$. Let $g$ be a function as guaranteed by (b), so that $\operatorname{dom}(g)=\operatorname{dom}(R)=\operatorname{ran}(f)$. Suppose $x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)$, so there is some unique $y\in\operatorname{ran}(g)$ such that $g(x)=y$. Since $\operatorname{ran}(g)\subseteq\operatorname{ran}(R)=\operatorname{dom}(f)$, then $f(y)=f(g(x))$ is well-defined. Moreover, since $\langle x,y\rangle\in g\subseteq R=f^{-1}$, then $\langle y,x\rangle\in f$, meaning $f(y)=y$ since $f$ is a function, so $f(g(x))=x$.
>
> $\bigl($(d)$\Rightarrow$(b)$\bigr)$ Let $R$ be a relation, and define a function $f$ by $f(x,y)=x$ for all $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$. Let $g$ be a function as guaranteed by (d), so by definition, $\operatorname{dom}(g)=\operatorname{ran}(f)=\operatorname{dom}(R)$, and $f(g(x))=x$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(R)$, meaning $g(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$. In particular, this means that $\operatorname{ran}(g)\subseteq R$, and since $g$ is a function, then by definition of $g$, $h=\operatorname{ran}(g)\subseteq R$ is a function, with $\operatorname{dom}(h)=\operatorname{dom}(g)=\operatorname{dom}(R)$. $\Box$

Comment: Are you sure that (c) is correct? Look at $f(1)=0$. Then $1\neq 0$ is in the domain of $f$, but there is no $g$ such that $g(1)\in f(1)$, since $f(1)$ is empty. Also, you meant $\operatorname{dom}(f)$ at the end, I guess?

Comment: Oh, dear! Well, that's not right, at all. Unfortunately, I'm not sure *where* I found (c), so it may have been mis-transcribed, or perhaps erroneous in the first place. Does (c) seem similar to any versions of AC with which you're familiar, Asaf?

Comment: Nothing I can immediately recognize, other than the obvious "indexed family have an indexed choice". But really that one is übertrivial.

Comment: Darn. Well, I'll peruse my list of forms, and see if I can figure out what it should be. If nothing else, now I know that my (b)$\implies$(c) proof is wrong.

Comment: It's wrong, but it's not *that* wrong. At some point when I was working on my thesis, I had a certain proof, and the proof was "correct", just the proposition I was proving kept moving around. (Later there was a problem on a much more fundamental level that made the validity of the claim dubious and irrelevant... but still, that reminds you that mathematical statement can be moving targets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the issues with (c) that I pointed out in the comments (you want $f(x)\neq\varnothing$, rather than $x\neq\varnothing$), and the superbly annoying "non-$0$" instead of "non-empty", this seems more or less correct.

Of course proving something false cannot possibly be right. I suspect that (c) should be phrased as "If $f(x)\neq\varnothing$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$, then there is $g$ such that $g(x)\in f(x)$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$".  With this in mind, the proof that (c) implies (a) works, since $f$ is the identity there; and (b)$\implies$(c) is also not that bad, once you switch the non-empty condition around.

---

It might be worth noting that proving (d)$\implies$(b) can be replaced by any of the other equivalents, since we already proved they are equivalent to AC, and the proof that (d) implies (a) is perhaps slightly more natural.

Comment: Looks like this is what I should have had: "For every function $f$ there is a function $g$ such that, for every $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$ with $f(x)\neq\emptyset,$ we have $g(x)\in f(x).$ This is AC 3 from *Consequences of the Axiom of Choice, II*. P.S.: Apologies for the $0=\emptyset$ convention. I got it from Kunen, which was my first foray into non-elementary set theory. It annoyed me, at first, but eventually, I just got used to it.

Comment: Did you also get un-used to it? :)

Comment: Eventually. I should probably go back and edit those old proofs for clarity's sake.

Comment: Yeah, or at least remove the note you left yourself.

Comment: Lol, yep! I removed that, corrected (c), and gave myself a more helpful note.

Comment: Was it "D'oh!"? :)

Comment: Not quite. ;-) As far as proving that (d)$\implies$(a), you're quite right. I took a pairwise disjoint family $\mathcal A$ of non-empty sets, defined $f$ on $\bigcup\mathcal A$ mapping each $x$ to the unique element $y\in\mathcal A$ such that $x\in y.$ Then letting $g$ as in (d), the range of $g$ is a choice set for $\mathcal A.$ That seem like what you had in mind?

Comment: That is indeed the obvious proof.